# How do I get user input in a turtle window?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm doing an assignment for school and would like to know how to collect user input directly from the turtle window rather than from the console. Is there the capacity for buttons in turtle or, if not, click events for certain areas so an area of the screen can act as a button?

Comment: Welcome to [so]! At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Answer (score 3):

User input can be obtained using the two graphic input methods that the turtle module provides:

- textinput(title, prompt)
- numinput(title, prompt, default=None, minval=None, maxval=None)

These are designed to help prevent some of the errors that console style input needs to trap.  These were introduced in Python 3 and are not available in Python 2 turtle.  However there are tkinter equivalents you can invoke from Python 2 when running turtle -- search SO for examples.

If you want a graphic button, my recommendation is you throw a turtle, or two, at the problem to become the button.  Size, shape and color the turtle appropriately and then add an `onclick()` handler onto the turtle, not the screen, so that you can then click on your button to invoke an action:

```
from turtle import Turtle, mainloop

BUTTON_SIZE = 60
CURSOR_SIZE = 20
FONT_SIZE = 18
FONT = ('Arial', FONT_SIZE, 'bold')
STATES = (('red', 'OFF'), ('green', 'ON'))
INITIAL_STATE = STATES[0]

def toggle_power(x, y):
    color, state = STATES[button.fillcolor() == 'red']

    button.fillcolor(color)
    marker.undo()
    marker.write(state, align='center', font=FONT)

color, state = INITIAL_STATE

button = Turtle('circle')
button.shapesize(BUTTON_SIZE / CURSOR_SIZE, outline=2)
button.color('black', color)
button.penup()
# button.goto(-200, 200)  # move the button into position

marker = Turtle(visible=False)
marker.penup()
marker.goto(button.xcor(), button.ycor() - BUTTON_SIZE/2 - FONT_SIZE - 2)
marker.write(state, align='center', font=FONT)

button.onclick(toggle_power)

mainloop()
```

The above button logic should work in either Python 3 or Python 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = screen.textinput(title="level", prompt="Which level do you want to play? Type beginner, intermediate, pro")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your answer might be more helpful to others if you explained how it worked and/or how it improves on the existing answer that's already been there for a while.

Answer (score 0):

When you work with an IDE like SublimeText which freezes with the regular
Python input(), this might be a good alternative:

```
import turtle as tu

tu.Screen().setup(15, 15)
# string input
name = tu.textinput("Name", "Please enter your name:")

# floating point input
age = tu.numinput("Age", "How old are you:", minval=0)

print(name)
print(age)
```